# Black Exported TIFF file Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification

I am trying to export the TIFF file from Google Earth Engine, but the exported file appears black.

```
var image = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .filterDate('2021-06-01', '2021-06-30')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first()
    .clip(roi))
  
  Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],min:0, max: 3000}, 'True colour image')

var classNames = heterogeneitybaresoil.merge(vegetation);
print(classNames)

var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4','B8', ];
var training = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: classNames,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 30
});
print(training);

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'landcover',
  inputProperties: bands
});


//Run the classification
var classified = image.select(bands).classify(classifier);

//Display classification
Map.centerObject(classNames, 11);
Map.addLayer(classified,
{min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['green','red']},
'classification');


// Create a task that you can launch from the Tasks tab.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified,
  description: 'Akamas',
  scale: 30
});
```

---

[image]

this is how looks like my exported tiff

the script of the above (in order to help you to run it)
https://code.earthengine.google.com/f8bc253d6c67799c92012441177173a0?hideCode=true

Comment: Add a screenshot of the exported raster.

Comment: Try visualizing the image in a GIS (e.g., ArcGIS, QGIS)

Comment: i have already open the tiff file in ArcGis Pro but file appears black too

Comment: the code of the script (if this help to run it) : https://code.earthengine.google.com/f8bc253d6c67799c92012441177173a0?hideCode=true

Comment: It's only all black because you haven't symbolized it (the Windows image viewer can't do this). Use unique values symbology in your GIS software. It's mostly 0s with a small patch of 1s (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP43z.png).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to export the red/green image, call Image.visualize on the output, using the same visualization parameters you're using to display it.  Otherwise, you're Exporting an image of 0s and 1s, which when you display it will appear black and almost-black.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified.visualize({min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['green','red']}),
  description: 'Akamas',
  scale: 30
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Mr. Noel