# Use ostu to count water, but export image is all black

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, landsat, image, otsu

When I run my code, it can be print image in map. But when I export to the Drive, it becomes all black image. Like this:[image]

There is my code, it will be a few long. Most part of them is OSTU code which is used to calculate the water. I need your help, sincerly.

```
var Name_List       = ee.List( ['垦利区','利津县','河口区','东营区'] );
var Inlist_Filter   = ee.Filter.inList( 'name', Name_List);
var roi   = roi.filter( Inlist_Filter );
var addVariable = function(image){
  var ndwi= image.expression(
              '(green-NIR)/(green+NIR)',{
              green:image.select('B4'),
              NIR:image.select('B6'),
            }).rename('ndwi')
  return image.addBands([ndwi]);
}

var landsat2 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LM02/C01/T2')
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .filterDate('1975-1-01', '1976-1-01')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER',5))
                  .map(addVariable)
                  .mosaic()
                  .clip(roi);
                  
var otsu = function(histogram) {
  var counts = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('histogram'));
  var means = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('bucketMeans'));
  var size = means.length().get([0]);
  var total = counts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
  var sum = means.multiply(counts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
  var mean = sum.divide(total);
  
  var indices = ee.List.sequence(1, size);
  
  // Compute between sum of squares, where each mean partitions the data.
  var bss = indices.map(function(i) {
    var aCounts = counts.slice(0, 0, i);
    var aCount = aCounts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
    var aMeans = means.slice(0, 0, i);
    var aMean = aMeans.multiply(aCounts)
        .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0])
        .divide(aCount);
    var bCount = total.subtract(aCount);
    var bMean = sum.subtract(aCount.multiply(aMean)).divide(bCount);
    return aCount.multiply(aMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)).add(
           bCount.multiply(bMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)));
  });
  // Return the mean value corresponding to the maximum BSS.
  return means.sort(bss).get([-1]);
};
var histogram = landsat2.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.histogram(),roi,30,null,null,true);
var threshold_Lat = otsu(histogram.get("ndwi"));
var mask = landsat2.gte(threshold_Lat);
var water_Lands = mask.rename("water");
Map.addLayer(landsat2);
Map.addLayer(mask.select('ndwi'));
Map.addLayer(mask.select("ndwi"),{min:0,max:1,palette:['#DDDDDD','#0099FF']},'water_Landsat_otsu_based');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image:mask.select("ndwi"),
  description: 'otsu2',
  region:roi,
  scale:30,
  maxPixels:1e13
})
```

Moreover, when I use the threshold value to calculate the water also meet this thing. (black image export)
the code likes `ndwi.gt(0.4)`

Comment: Have you tried examining the output file in a GIS? It may well hold the values you expect but the viewer in Google Drive cannot render tiff files.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. After tell you!

Comment: you said may be right, ( by Q GIS ), moreover I chose another way behind. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From Mr. Noel: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408774/202572
This code may sovle the problem, if you have other ways. You can also share to us!